# Reconstruction of a probabilistically sparse signal

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, signal-processing, sparsity

Consider we have a vector $\boldsymbol{x}_1^n$ which has a sparse structure in the sense that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(x_i=0)=\alpha>0.
\end{equation}
Further, assume that we have a sampled version $\boldsymbol{y}_1^m = A_{m\times n} \boldsymbol{x}_1^n$.

Can we lower bound the probability of the exact reconstruction of $\boldsymbol{x}_1^n$ using $\boldsymbol{y}_1^m$ and some conditions on $A$?

I guess there must be a weaker condition than on the SPARK (minimum linearly dependent columns) of $A$.

Comment: Restricted Isometry Principle?

Comment: That is for sparse vectors. I need something weeker.

Comment: If you don't get a response here, you have more luck on dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 Thank you!